# i am getting invalid format while getting data from .xlsx file using selenium webdriver

Tags: excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The actual value i want to import integer value from excel to my application inputbox is 1122 but i am getting value like 1122.0 i am using poi files
i am not getting interger values properly can anyone help me[image]

```
FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream("path of the file");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fi);
        Sheet s=wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int rcnt=s.getLastRowNum();
        for(int i=0; i<rcnt; i++)
        {
            Row r=s.getRow(i+1);
            int ccnt=r.getLastCellNum();
            for(int j=0; j<ccnt; j++)
            {
                Cell c=r.getCell(j);
                if(c.getCellType()==c.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                {
                    data[i][j]=c.getStringCellValue();
                }
                if(c.getCellType()==c.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                {

                        data[i][j]=String.valueOf(c.getNumericCellValue());
                    }
                }
            }


        return data;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(c.getCellType()==c.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
            {Double value = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            Long longValue = value.longValue();
                            temp = new String(longValue.toString());

                    data[i][j]=temp;
                }
            }
```

Try to use this, i had used this long time back, i dont remember exactly now but may be you will the desired output